# Uninstall multiple versions of Adobe Bridge

Tags: macos, adobe, adobe-bridge

After installing Photoshop CS6 extended yesterday, I noticed that I have multiple versions of Adobe Photoshop and related programs (like Adobe Bridge), and they take up a lot of space.

I don't really use Adobe Bridge, but I have CS3 (came with Photoshop CS3 extended), CS4 (came with Photoshop Elements 8) and CS6 on my mac, is it safe to remove the older two versions and just keep Adobe Bridge CS6 without affecting the functionality of Photoshop CS3 and Elements 8?

What's the best way to do a clean uninstall of the programs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has a [cleaning tool](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html) that helps. If I remember correctly, put the old apps in the can, then run the tool, then delete the trash. If that doesn't work, read the cleaning tool instructions :)

Answer (score 0):

There will be an uninstaller on your machine to do this for you already, normally I'd write out some instructions for you here but in this case it might be easier to give you a [link to adobe's instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/remove-creative-suite-3-cs3.html#main_Uninstall_Creative_Suite_3_editions_and_products_on_Mac_OS) which also comes with a really simple video. :-).